# GRE tunnel not accept NAT

Tags: networking, debian, pfsense

On server 1 installed pfsense. On server 2 installed debian.
I've created GRE tunnel:

GRE pfsense settings

[image: 123]
[image: GRE pfsense settings]

The tunnels are working:

[image: 654]
[image: 543]

Why NAT rule not works?(all ports open, filter reloaded)

[image: 23]